# What is the Opaque in this code?

Tags: c, types

These days almost everybody has heard about the HeartBleed exploit.

If you check the code which is the origin of the problem, you can find the following structure:

```
struct {
      HeartbeatMessageType type;
      uint16 payload_length;
      opaque payload[HeartbeatMessage.payload_length];
      opaque padding[padding_length]; 
   } HeartbeatMessage;
```

It has been a while since the last time I programmed actively on C but I still use it to program little programs or snippets.

The point is that I have never used `opaque` and I would like to know what does exactly `opaque` stand for.

Comment: There are no pointers in that struct, `void` or otherwise. There are two arrays. The declaration is not legal C code anyway, it just gives you a general idea of how the message is laid out in the memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"*Opaque*" is often used in commercial and internal/proprietary APIs when you just need to "fill a gap" in a C/C++ declaration.

Since you don't know if that type is a pointer (in that case you would know its size) or an entire structure/class, you can't deduce anything and thus the code serves as a general idea of how the memory is laid out.

They **hide information from you**. It's a common technique especially used for security measures when there's sensible code like the one you posted above.

Comment: +1 And one more question: Does the word actually appear in the code? From you answer I understand it should only appear in documentation.

Comment: Or is there an appropriate `#define` or `typdef` somewhere?

Comment: It can appear in the code if it's typedef'd, but nobody uses that since you can hide the implementation in other better ways (e.g. behind a header and linking against a .lib/.dll or by using pointers to something else and losing their type with void*, also if that is a bit type-unsafe). They're often used in documentation spots so that you can't figure out how data is laid out in memory and, if a security researcher wants to do that, he has to reverse-engineer the stuff himself (probably illegal).

Comment: @DavidKernin I initially posted my question asking what was the difference between `opaque` and `void *` but I realized, after n.m. comments, that it wasn't very accurate and that it was like a XY Problem. But I was so inclined that it was somehow equivalent `void *` referencing an array ... Your answer and comments makes it clear now.